# Redirecting user to a webpage with PHP

Tags: php, html

So I have an HTML webpage with a form on it. The form sends its data to a PHP file on the server.

After processing the form data with the PHP file, I want to redirect the user to another HTML webpage.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually done by PHP `header` function, like this:

`header("Location: http://your-domain.com/your-page.php");`

You can read more about it in [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) or from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php).

Answer (score 0):

Though this question is a duplicate. I'll answer it. You do it as follows:

```
header("Location: http://yourwebsite.com/otherpage.php");
```

Answer (score -1):

In PHP you have to use below code snippet to redirect from one location to the other.

```
header("Location: page.php");
```